# Deserialize Multidict using Colander

Tags: pyramid, pylons, colander

On a website I have a [`<select>` element with `multiple` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) like so:

```
<select value="name" multiple>
  <option value="willi">Willi</option>
  <option value="wonka">Wonka</option>
</select>
```

If both options are selected, then the [Pyramid](https://trypyramid.com/) server’s view function receives the [request object](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.POST) with a [multidict](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/api/multidict.html) instance:

```
 MultiDict([('name', 'willi'), ('name', 'wonka')])
```

Because I’ve been using [Colander](https://github.com/Pylons/colander) for data validation and deserialization, I wanted to write a schema for this instance… but after digging around the documentation I’m beginning to wonder if that’s at all possible?

So, how would I deserialize this particular multidict using Colander?

Comment: You can see example selects and their Colander schema in the [Deform demo](https://deformdemo.pylonsproject.org/select/). BTW, it would be a good idea to have an empty string value, else the select will submit the first option if the user does not deliberately choose an option.

Comment: Thanks @StevePiercy! Found a [demo with select multiple](https://deformdemo.pylonsproject.org/select_with_multiple/) on that page: I see it uses a generic [colander.Schema](https://colander.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#colander.Schema) with a [Set](https://colander.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#colander.Set) type node. The `widget` property is new to me, and I’m not using [deform](https://github.com/Pylons/deform) in my project… Hm. Perhaps a manual implementation of [deserialize()](https://colander.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#colander.SchemaNode.deserialize) would work?

Comment: I have not used Colander without Deform or Peppercorn, but one could use Colander without them, as you have found in Colander's API docs. Here's an [example in the Colander narrative docs](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/basics.html#deserialization).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll want to use something like `request.POST.mixed()` which will return a list for the `name` key if multiple values were sent (but not a list if just one value) combined with maybe a colander preparer to convert it to a list if it isn't already.